# What part of the implementation in Enum shape the behavior of `isinstance`?

Tags: python, enums

`isinstance(x, E)`, when applied on a Enum's child class `E`, checks for whether the first parameter `x` is a member of `e`. For example, with the following definition:

```py
from enum import Enum

class E(Enum):
    X = 1
    Y = 2
    Z = 3
```

`isinstance(E.X, E)` returns `True`, but `isinstance(1, E)` returns `False`. I'm puzzled how the [`Enum` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/enum.py) makes this work: I don't even see `__instancecheck__` being overridden. How does the Enum implementation make `isinstance` calls work in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special done at runtime to handle `isinstance`. The special behaviour for enums is all done during class construction when you derive from `Enum`.

Eg.

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class E(Enum):
...     X = 1
...     Y = 2
... 
>>> 
>>> type(E.X)
<enum 'E'>
>>> E.X == 1
False
```

`Enum` has `EnumMeta` as its metaclass, and the special handling is in `EnumMeta.__new__` which builds the `E` enum class. What it does, among other things, is to replace all the attributes you define as ints with instances of `E` with the given value.